# Image not showing up in Facebook shares

Tags: image, debugging, facebook-opengraph, sharing

We are having problems with Facebook not showing images, which we noticed from 17 May.

We have images tagged in og:image, and this is showing up as a blank white space in the object debugger. Clicking on this blank white image/space shows the actual image expected in a new browser window, there are no issues with viewing the image within or outside the network (we tested using different devices and proxies to simulate access from outside Singapore, which is our main audience). The image is 300x225, but the debugger also show the "image not big enough" warning.

Sample scenario (HTTP removed from some links):

URL in question: www.hungrygowhere.com/dining-guide/what-to-eat/5-family-friendly-restaurants-to-book-online-*aid-53763f00/

og:image meta on the page: `<meta property="og:image" content="http://staticc04.insing.com/images/f3/e0/10/00/pc_300x225.jpg" />`

Warning on the debugger page: "Provided og:image is not big enough. Please use an image that's at least 200x200 px. Image 'staticc04.insing.com/images/f3/e0/10/00/pc_300x225.jpg' will be used instead."

Noticeably the src attribute on the debugger is similar to this: fbexternal-a.akamaihd.net/safe_image.php?d=AQAfsdJpTPWk1IqW&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstaticc05.insing.com%2Fimages%2Fe2%2Fdb%2F10%2F00%2Fpc_300x225.jpg and going directly to this image via the browser shows a blank 1x1 gif. We tested using a 600x600 image (after seeing a post about maintaining aspect ratio) but it's the same: external.ak.fbcdn.net/safe_image.php?d=AQDZBb-0AZjyOp_B&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstaticc03.insing.com%2Fimages%2F57%2Fde%2F10%2F00%2Fstb_600x600.jpg

Our hypothesis is that safe_image.php is not accepting the image it retrieves, but we have no idea what or why this is happening.

We have a ticket open on the Facebook bugs support forum for this (developers.facebook.com/bugs/647132798635052) but no response after the initial round of clarifications, but we are hard pressed to find a solution.

There were no changes to our image storage solution over this timeframe. No rewrites or redirects, the image URLs are files by their own right.

**Edited to add:**

It is strictly safe_image.php that is choking on our image. See a screenshot from the object debugger: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CzU34.png

The image on the right is the same og:image, but since it's accessed directly by FB (not going through safe_image.php), it shows up.

We have been checking logs and we are returning HTTP status 206 to Facebook (we have been doing this for a while now) but this was changed to return 200 at all times. No change, we are still not getting any images.

Comment: Hi, did you solve this problem?